# Which layers of the language is dealing with co-reference resolution and how to solve it computationaly?

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, semantics, nlp, discourse

Which [layers of the language](http://www.learningplace.com.au/deliver/content.asp?pid=40456) is dealing with co-reference resolution and what are the steps to solve this problem in NLP?

Comment: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml

Comment: Mind adding some more explanations? Not all will be able to understand your question as is. Adding details/context would help.

Comment: Yeah, if somebody told you Language Layers _M_ through _P_ were dealing with  co-reference resolution, how much would that help?

Comment: @jlawler Were you replying to me?

Comment: @jlawler: Gotta love them LLs! (I think he means something like how anaphora works, so that would be pragmatics?) @ ARZ: I'm afraid the problem cannot be solved until we manage to build an artificial intelligence many levels higher in complexity than what current science allows us. Some simple cases in an extremely limiting context may be resolved automatically. You might want to browse around Wikipedia a bit, starting [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)#Anaphor_resolution).

Comment: @Alenanno: I put a hyperlink for LLs.

Comment: @Cerberus: Pragmatics or Discourse?

Comment: @ARZ: All perspectives are interconnected and overlap, but I would say mainly pragmatics.

Comment: Like the hierarchy displayed [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Semantics.pdf), then. Under that interpretation, coreference resolution involves all the layers; it's an opportunistic process. And often fails.